# Use COUNT and JOIN in a same query SQL

Tags: sql

My tables:

`Customers`:

```
+------+----+
| Name | ID |
+------+----+
| Phu  | 12 |
| Nam  | 23 |
| Mit  | 33 |
+------+----+
```

`Orders`:

```
+----+------------+
| ID |   Order    |
+----+------------+
| 12 | Laptop     |
| 12 | Mouse      |
| 33 | Smartphone |
| 23 | Keyboard   |
| 33 | Computer   |
+----+------------+
```

I want to get output like this:

```
+------+--------+
| Name | Orders |
+------+--------+
| Phu  |      2 |
| Mit  |      2 |
+------+--------+
```

I use this query but this doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    COUNT(*) AS 'Orders'
FROM 
    Orders a
INNER JOIN 
    Customers b ON a.ID = b.ID
GROUP BY 
    a.ID 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

It has the error like this:

> Column 'Customers.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Every column you select has to be in the group by clause. So use Group by b.Name

Comment: It's a **query** (not a *querry* - one `r` is quite enough)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment every column in the select statement has to be in the group by clause.

```
SELECT  Name, COUNT(*) AS 'Orders'
FROM    Orders a
INNER JOIN  Customers b
ON a.ID = b.ID
GROUP BY b.Name
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Comment: If same name in customer table then what happen?

Comment: Then group by Id first. GROUP BY a.Id, b.Name

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.Name, COUNT(o.ID) AS Orders
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.ID = o.ID
GROUP BY o.ID
HAVING Orders > 1
```

Working **Sqlfiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/869790/4